# byte array to blob javascript

Tags: javascript, html, wcf

I'm working on a windows8 machine, using IIS 8 and .NET 4.5.

I've created a WCF restful service that returns a BLOB as a JSON string byte[]. On my client side i get the images and i try to read them in the following manner:

```
getTileUrl: function (tilePoint, zoom, tile) {
    var z = this._getOffsetZoom(zoom);
    var x = tilePoint.x;
    var y = tilePoint.y;
    var base64Prefix = 'data:image/gif;base64,';
this.mbTilesDB.transaction(function(tx) {
        console.log("executing SQL!!!!");
        tx.executeSql("SELECT tile_data FROM images INNER JOIN map ON images.tile_id = map.tile_id WHERE zoom_level = ? AND tile_column = ? AND tile_row = ?", [z, x, y],function(tx,result){
            tile.src = base64Prefix + result.rows.item(0).tile_data; //.rows.item(0).tile_data;
        }, function (er) {
            console.log('error with executeSql', er);
        });
  }); 
},
```

I get the error message:

Failed to load resource data:image/gif;base64,137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,1,0…,237,255,1,100,245,49,110,153,90,168,241,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,174,66,96,130

I'm pretty sure that the item is stored in the wrong format. Ive been looking around but i can't find a clear example on how to parse a byte[] to a blob file. I'm developing on my desktop using Google chrome, but eventualy it will need to work in Phonegap.

So my question: How to i convert the byte[] to the correct BLOB format?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Ok I Solved it. I'm returning a base64 string instead of a byte[]. 
tile_data =  Convert.ToBase64String((byte[])r["tile_data"]),

Comment: If you want to use JS to solve the problem, maybe this article can help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Base64_encoding_and_decoding#Solution_.232_.E2.80.93_rewriting_atob%28%29_and_btoa%28%29_using_TypedArrays_and_UTF-8